# Get the size of an Image

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

I'm making a little Windows Forms app to select an image from your PC, and then display the image in `pictureBox1` using the filepath.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

Now I want to put the dimensions (in pixels) of the image in an other textbox.

Is this possible the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can get the size when setting the image using `ImageLocation` (As the PictureBox handles loading internally). Try loading the image using `Image.FromFile`, and using the `Width` and `Height` properties of that.

```
var image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
pictureBox1.Image = image;
// Now use image.Width and image.Height
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
MessageBox.Show("Width: " + img.Width + ", Height: " + img.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the image using `Image.FromFile` method

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Put your `image` in the `pictureBox1`

```
pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

What you need is `System.Drawing.Image` class. The size of the image is in the `image.Size` property. But if you want to get `Width` and `Height` separately, you can use `image.Width` and `image.Height` respectively

Then in your other `TextBox` (suppose the name is `textBox2`) You can simply assign the `Text` property like this,

```
textBox2.Text = "Width: " + image.Width.ToString() + ", Height: " + image.Height.ToString();
```

Complete code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        Image image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = image; //simply put the image here!
        textBox2.Text = "Width: " + image.Width.ToString() + ", Height: " + image.Height.ToString();
    }
}
```